# spark or mapreduce not connect with hbase some time

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, apache-spark, apache-zookeeper

I write a spark program in which using HBase for data input. Run this program some 1-3 time well.
But try after more than 3 (most cases) times it give exception. Find Below..

```
    14/09/23 19:18:45 INFO util.RegionSizeCalculator: Calculating region sizes for table "Input-data".
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.hadoop.net.DNS.reverseDns(DNS.java:92)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase.reverseDNS(TableInputFormatBase.java:228)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase.getSplits(TableInputFormatBase.java:191)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.getPartitions(NewHadoopRDD.scala:94)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:204)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:202)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:202)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedRDD.getPartitions(MappedRDD.scala:28)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:204)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:202)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:202)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1135)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:904)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.count(JavaRDDLike.scala:368)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD.count(JavaRDD.scala:32)
at com.my.HbaseNaiveBayes.main(HbaseNaiveBayes.java:116)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.launch(SparkSubmit.scala:328)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:75)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

And i try to connect using hbase shell. It work fine.I run scan and count command give accurate output.

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: Please post the code giving the error.

Comment: 14/09/23 19:46:27 INFO util.RegionSizeCalculator: Calculating region sizes for table "Input-data".
14/09/23 19:46:28 WARN mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase: Cannot resolve the host name for machineName/172.19.2.22 because of javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: DNS name not found [response code 3]; remaining name '22.2.19.172.in-addr.arpa'